# How to replace the "." with ":" in the proof environment?

Tags: theorems, punctuation, amsthm

I have seen a similar post here [How to remove the "." in the proof environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31354/how-to-remove-the-in-the-proof-environment).
But I don't know how I can modify [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31354/how-to-remove-the-in-the-proof-environment/31365#31365)  to replace `.` with `:` by using `etoolbox`.

Comment: You could use the easier way with the `thmtools` (see answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31355/8042 ) by writing `headpunct={:}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to get ***Proof:*** (boldface italic) is to say

```
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\bfseries Proof:}
```

The `\@addpunct` command will not add its argument if it's preceded by a punctuation mark, so no change to the definition of the `proof` environment is necessary.

Note: the italic shape is already selected, so it's only necessary to add `\bfseries`. No braces are needed, as the heading is typeset as the optional argument to `\item`, which forms a group by itself.

One can, alternatively, patch the environment's definition in order to change `\@addpunct{.}` into `\@addpunct{:}` and to add `\bfseries`. Patching the environment with `etoolbox` is tricky, because the environment has an optional argument:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{:}}{}{}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname{\itshape}{\itshape\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother
```

With the `xpatch` package it's easier:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\proof{\@addpunct{.}}{\@addpunct{:}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\proof{\itshape}{\itshape\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: A very interesting fact about the `\@addpunct` command which I didn't know.

Answer (score 7):

Take the code for the `proof` environment from the sources of the [amsthm](http://tan.org/pkg/amsthm) package and modify it accordingly.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{:}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{proof}
    This is a proof.
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I can remove the "." at the end as in the link I supplied above and redefine the *proof name* with a ":" at the end as follows.
`\def\proofname{\emph{\textbf{Proof:}}}`
But I find this no good.

Comment: This is the way I do it when I want to change `.`->`:` or to change the font.

Comment: @bkarpuz.  Do you understand this answer?  I am completely confused.  I find the other answer below more helpful and clear.

Comment: **@J G**. I used the first one supplied in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44114/9955 by **egreg**.

Comment: @bkarpuz: Then you should accept [his answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44114/1063) and vote it up (if not done yet).

Comment: **@Thorsten Donig**. Thank you for your notification. I voted it but I didn't know how to accept it. But done now!