# Suppress proof heading in proof environment

Tags: math-mode

I'm using the `proof` environment defined by `\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}`, mainly so the qed box is inserted automatically in the correct place.

But I don't want a heading (or the blank row) before the mathematics. So I use

```
\begin{proof}[]
```

with nothing in the `[]`. But I still get a period in the generated text. Is there a better way of suppressing the line entirely?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to define a new `proofw` environment (in this way you still have access to the standard `proof`) in a similar fashion to `amsmthm`'s proof, but suppressing the name and the punctuation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{proofw}{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A standard test proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proofw}
A modified test proof.
\end{proofw}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more freedom in customization, another option is to use [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) as a front-end for `amsthm and` define your environment controlling all attributes (spacing after and before, addition of end-mark, no head) at will:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=0pt, 
  spacebelow=0pt,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  postheadspace=0em,
  qed=\qedsymbol,
  headpunct={},
  headformat={}
]{withouthead}
\declaretheorem[style=withouthead]{proofw}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
A standard test proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proofw}
A modified test proof.
\end{proofw}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The only pity with this is that it seems to insert extra space above the proof body. Perhaps I'm fighting the environment too hard here.

Comment: @Bathsheba Change `\topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax` to `\topsep0\p@\@plus6\p@\relax` and you'll kill the spacing. Or use [`thmtools`](www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) as a front-end to define your own environment without head but with end-mark. In some minutes I'll add this option.

Comment: @Bathsheba I added a little example using `thmtools`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the stock `proof` environment, by adding an appropriate definition for `\proofname`.

Since `proof` does

```
\item[\hskip\labelsep\itshape#1\@addpunct{.}]
```

where `#1` is the optional argument to `\begin{proof}` with default value `\proofname`, all we need is to nullify the spacing and to set a high enough space factor to make `\@addpunct` that a punctuation symbol is already present.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for mock text

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\proofname}{\hskip-\labelsep\spacefactor3000 }

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[Proof of the main theorem]
This one is obvious.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

In case you do want the title, you can still give it explicitly.

[image]